# Thread.Start not working

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using the functions of the following class to invoke a messagebox. I am using thread.Start method to show the messagebox. The problem is it is not reaching to the respective function  when thread.Start is called. Am i missing anything?

```
class MessageManager
{
  string _message;
  public MessageManager(string message)
  {
    _message = message;
  }

  public void ShowBigMessage()
  {
    Thread thread = new Thread(DisplayBigMessage);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
    thread.Start();

    // thread.Join(); 
  }

  public void ShowNormalMessage()
  {
    Thread thread = new Thread(DisplayNormalMessage);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
    thread.Start();
    //thread.Join(); 
  }

  private void DisplayBigMessage()
  {
    BigAppMessage appMessage = new BigAppMessage(_message);
    appMessage.Show();
  }

  private void DisplayNormalMessage()
  {
    AppMessage appMessage = new AppMessage(_message);
    appMessage.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

This is called inside a thread/delegate as below. I added this code into my program becuase it was raising

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require
>   this.

exception before

```
MessageManager message = new MessageManager("This is a test message.");

                    message.ShowBigMessage();





  public partial class BigAppMessage : Window
    {
        public BigAppMessage(String message)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myControl.setMessage(message); // mycontrol is just user control with a                   
                                           //label on it
        }       

    }
```

Comment: Are you saying it isn't reaching the function because the message box doesn't appear, or did you actually set a breakpoint in the function and it's never getting hit?

Comment: Post the **AppMessage** and **BigAppMessage** classes if you want help. I am going to guess your not setting the owner handle for the MessageBox the correct way.  You also never actually call **ShowBigMessage()** so its not shocking your **MessageBox** is not being shown

Comment: When you actually post the code your trying to use I will consider changing my negative vote to a positive vote.  At this point the question CANNOT be answered.  Your exact question is also not exactly clear since your code doesn't do anything of substance.

Comment: i set a breakpoint and it never get hit.

Comment: @logeeks - Post the code where you actually call **ShowNormalMessage()** because you don't in the code you posted.

Comment: @AdamRobinson - He claims his code is not working, the only problem is, he is never using the method, that would start the thread.

Comment: edited to add the calling part

Comment: @logeeks - Use Hans Passant's modification.  You still didn't post the BigAppMessage class.

Answer (score 2):

The Show() method requires a message loop.  Fix:

```
  private void DisplayBigMessage()
  {
    Application.Run(new BigAppMessage(_message));
  }
```

There's already a message loop built into the ShowDialog() method.  Using a thread to just display a window has no advantages, only problems.

Comment: the messagebox has to be displayed when program encounters some problem.

Comment: Well, that's what message boxes are used for.  Having it disappear behind another window because you display it on a thread would be an example of a problem.  Completely unnoticeable to the user since it isn't modal to the ui and doesn't have a taskbar button.

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio go to Debug->Exceptions and check the "thrown" box next to CLR exceptions.  this will tell you where your problem is. Probably its a cross thread issue since you would ordinarily only interact with the UI on the UI thread.